# What is Lubuntu 13.04's default clipboard manager?

Tags: ubuntu, clipboard, lubuntu, ubuntu-13.04

I can't figure out what the default clipboard manager is on my Lubuntu installation. I see i have `xclipboard` and `lxclipboard` installed, but if I run them from a terminal, both of them say `another clipboard is already running` (`xclipboard` terminates, but `lxclipboard` seems to keep running until I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>). I haven't explicitly installed any other clipboard managers (like `parcellite`), and searching for "clip" in Synaptic doesn't show any packages installed that contain a clipboard manager (except for `x11-apps`, which contains `xclipboard`). Running `ps ax | grep clip` gets me nothing, either.

I'm looking for this because I want to be able to directly edit my clipboard without installing anything extra, if possible. I know of `xclip` and will install it if it's the only way to directly manipulate my clipboard, but the ability to see the clipboard and modify it should be possible here without it... right?

EDIT: Ultimately, I would like to know how to go about editing the clipboard without extra software. [It's been established that it *should* be possible](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/lubuntu-users/2012-February/000393.html), but I have no idea how?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have parcellite? What does `apropos clipboard` return?

Comment: `xclipboard (1)       - X clipboard client`

Comment: Also, pretty sure I don't have parcellite installed: `The program 'parcellite' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install parcellite`